# cellForRowAtIndexPath: crashes when trying to access arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am loading in data to a `UITableView`, from a custom `UITableViewCell` (own class and nib). It works great, until I try to access the `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` for some arrays.

I'll post my code first, it will probably be easier for you to understand what I mean then.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]){
                cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    cell.titleLabel.text = [postsArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [postsArrayDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[postsArrayImgSrc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

The odd thing is, it does work when it loads in the first three cells (they are 130px high), but crashes when I try to scroll down. (Aka, the log shows three numbers before it crashes, `0, 1, 2`)

**So, as a summary, the `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` runs 3*3 times successfully, but when I try to scroll down in the app, loading in new cells, the app crashes with the following error:**

```
2010-05-30 14:00:43.122 app[2582:207] -[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a44bf0
2010-05-30 14:00:43.124 app[2582:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a44bf0'
// Stack
    0   CoreFoundation                   0x02398c99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024e65de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0239a7ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x0230a496 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0230a052 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   myappname                        0x00002ab1 -[HomeTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 605
```

---

Additional information on the arrays:

The arrays are created in the `.h` file:

```
NSArray *postsArrayDate;
NSArray *postsArrayTitle;
NSArray *postsArrayComments;
NSArray *postsArrayImgSrc;
```

And filled in the `viewDidLoad:`:

```
NSURL *urlPosts = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite/myphpfile.php?posts=2"]; //returns data in this format: DATA1#Data1.1#data1.2~DATA2#data2.1#~ and so on.
NSError *lookupError = nil;
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPosts encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&lookupError];
postsData = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
[data release], data = nil;
urlPosts = nil;
postsArrayDate = [[postsData objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
postsArrayTitle = [[postsData objectAtIndex:3] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
postsArrayComments = [[postsData objectAtIndex:4] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
postsArrayImgSrc = [[postsData objectAtIndex:5] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
```

How can I fix this crash?

Comment: If anyone want to explain to me why using self.array in viewDidLoad when filling the arrays fixed it, I'll accept that answer. Thank you.

Comment: And what the self. part does in other comparisons.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't got the slightest idea why adding `self.` to `postsArrayDate` etc. solved it...

Comment: @Douwe M: Hint: retaining of objects... :)

Comment: Had the same problem, can anyone elaborate a little more on why self. makes the difference? I am a little confused here.

Comment: When accessing a property a value without using `self.property`, the property won't retain the value. The value will be set, but it will disappear in a few microseconds.

Comment: ****  I had the same issue, addressing the "self." array fixed it.  ****  The NSArray was only representing the singular instance of the "ObjectAtIndex:#" which ultimately was being treated as a NSString.  When creating the NSArray, I created tempArray, filled it with objects, set it equal to MyArray, the released tempArray.  But setting it equal to "MyArray = tempArray;" failed.  Required to address the array OBJECT with "self.MyArray = tempArray;" which works 100% !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is this:

```
-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d10c20
```

In other words, you tried to run `objectAtIndex:` on an `NSString` (`NSCFString`), which of course does not support this method.

You call `objectAtIndex:` three times, in these lines:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [postsArrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.dateLabel.text = [postsArrayDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[postsArrayImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

So it appears that `postsArrayTitle`, `postsArrayDate`, or `postsArrayImg` isn't an `NSArray`, but an `NSString`.

Comment: Nope, can't be it, it crashes when I try to NSLog it, too.

Comment: **EDIT** I tried to NSLog with %@ instead of %d. But I know that those arrays contains strings, but they are arrays.

Comment: And also, it can't be that, because, as I wrote, the first three cells (before scrolling down) loads in perfectly from these arrays.

Comment: Well, it could be there's some other problem, but this is definitely why that error occurred.

Comment: Yep, that works. `NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);` also works, if i put it at the absolute beginning of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it will also print the number 3 before it crashes.

Answer (score 3):

** I had the same issue, addressing the "self." array fixed it. **

---

The NSArray was only representing the singular instance of the "ObjectAtIndex:#" which ultimately was being treated as a NSString. When creating the NSArray, I created tempArray, filled it with objects, set it equal to MyArray, the released tempArray. But setting it equal to "MyArray = tempArray;" failed. Required to address the array OBJECT with "self.MyArray = tempArray;" which works 100% !!